# students and teachers in a class_instruction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Setting up the database, I am just curious if I did it correctly, as it looks a bit off.   There are people, who have a user account, and a role (teacher or student).   they are participants in a class (where a class has many students and teachers; a student has many classes; a teacher has many classes).  I think my class_instruction model is off in the DB, but please tell me if it will work, or if there is a better way (like maybe with a has_many_through table of participants)

schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130524160107) do

  create_table "class_instructions", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "time"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "person_id"
  end

  add_index "class_instructions", ["person_id"], :name => "index_class_instructions_on_person_id"

  create_table "people", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "firstName"
    t.string   "lastName"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  add_index "people", ["user_id"], :name => "index_people_on_user_id"

  create_table "roles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "user_roles", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "role_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  add_index "user_roles", ["role_id"], :name => "index_user_roles_on_role_id"
  add_index "user_roles", ["user_id"], :name => "index_user_roles_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

end
```

My concern is that the person_id is part of the class.  Is this correct?

ClassInsturction.rb :

```
class ClassInstruction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :people
  has_many :cassignments
  has_many :assignments, :through => :cassignments

  def className
    self.name
  end

  def classAssignments
    return self.cassignments
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a joining table that has both class and people and use has many through. If people have many classes and classes have many people you can not do this any other way.

Comment: I don't think your user roles needs to use has many through. Unless a user can be both a teacher and a student.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen usually belongs_to with singular form:

```
belongs_to :person
```

I am not sure if this is what you are asking for though.